# quickreport exporttortf doc without textbox

Tags: delphi-7, quickreports, export-to-word

I use psqrfilters to export a quickreport in .doc using exporttortf. It work´s fine, but all the text in doc is inside a textbox.

Is there a configuration to save it without a textbox ?

ExportToRTF(QuickRep1,'c:\test.doc') ;

Comment: ExportToRTF accepts two arguments, the report and the filename. There's no way to pass it any other options, so there's no way to change its output.